# How to animate a tiled grid in Processing

Tags: java, grid, processing, nested-loops

I am currently trying to create a grid of tiles in PROCESSING.... and I want each tile to appear after the other. (First row, left to right, second row, left to right and so on).... I get it to make each row of tiles appear one by one by a combination of frameCount and modulo in the nested loop.... but how to let each tile appear after another?
I've tried using the same method on the x-axis loop - this makes the grid appear from LEFT/UP to RIGHT/DOWN.... I tried changing the frameCount by multiplying times 10.... but this doesn't seem to be the correct maths.... do I need to use a conditional statement on one of the loops? Like if tiles is equal times round second row, third and so on? This is what I came up with so far:

```
void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  float tiles = 10;
  float tileSize = width/tiles;
  translate(tileSize/2, tileSize/2);
  for (int x = 0; x < tiles; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < frameCount/tiles % tiles; y++) { 
      fill(0, 255, 0);
      rect(x*tileSize, y*tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for any kind of help or hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Processing is broken for some reason, you can past the following code to the p5js online editor

Is this what you want?

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  let tiles = 10;
  let tileSize = width/tiles;
  for(let y = 0; y < tiles; y++){
    for(let x = 0; x < tiles; x++){
      if(x + 10*y < frameCount)
      rect(x*tileSize, y*tileSize, tileSize, tileSize)
    }
  }
  
}
```

https://editor.p5js.org/